# AsyncTask e Fragmentos

Tags: android, android-fragment, async, asynctask

Olá, sou novato em desenvolvimento e tenho algumas dúvidas.

Tenho que implementar um novo layout, onde:

1. Converti as activities que carregam os dados em fragmentos;
2. Numa nova activity o fragmento do gráfico fica no topo e o que carrega a lista fica abaixo, dividindo a tela.

MetaActivity: convertido para fragment, traz uma ListView, ao clicar em um registro vai para a activity FragmentosPeriodosAnterioresActivity

--FragmentosPeriodosAnterioresActivity

----(Fragment Top) PeriodoGraphActivity (convertido para fragment)

----(Fragment Bottom) PeriodoActivity (convertido para fragment) carrega os dados num ArrayList com os dados, dentro do metodo assíncrono

O motivo que as converti ao invés de criar em uma nova classe com a nomenclatura de fragmento é porque o Async não executa a rotina, só funciona nesta classe...

A classe PeriodoActivity atualmente no método onActivityCreated carrega as metas em listview da webservice a partir do AsyncTask e os guarda uma variável "global":

```
...
callBack = new AsyncCallBack() {
  public void onTesting(Object res) {
    ...
    Intent listaMetas = getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putSerializable("ListaPeriodo", metas);
    listaMetas.putExtras(extras);
  }
}
```

A Classe PeriodoGraphActivity (Carrega um AndroidPlot com os dados gerados no fragmento PeriodoActivity e guardados no serializable "ListaPeriodo") // no método onStart()

```
Intent listaMetas = getActivity().getIntent(); 
ArrayList<Cenario1> teste = new ArrayList<Cenario1>();
metas =  (ArrayList<Cenario1>) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializable("ListaPeriodo"); // retorna nulo
```

-> Minha grande dúvida, é possível escolher o momento ou em que o método assíncrono é executado?

-> É de boas práticas carregar dados em assíncrono nos fragmentos?

O log do android monitor do lifecicle dos fragmentos e activity:

```
...
03-31 09:32:03.678 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosMetaActivity onCreateView (not implemented)
03-31 09:32:03.686 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosMetaActivity onCreateView (not implemented)
03-31 09:32:03.780 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosMetaActivity onCreateView (not implemented)
03-31 09:32:13.717 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosMetaActivity onPause (not implemented)
03-31 09:32:13.780 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosPeriodosAnterioresActivity onStart (not implemented)
03-31 09:32:13.780 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoGraphActivity onCreate 
03-31 09:32:13.780 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoGraphActivity onCreateView 
03-31 09:32:13.842 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosPeriodosAnterioresActivity onStart (not implemented)
03-31 09:32:13.842 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoActivity onCreate
03-31 09:32:13.842 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoActivity onCreateView
03-31 09:32:13.866 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosPeriodosAnterioresActivity onCreate
03-31 09:32:13.866 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoGraphActivity onActivityCreated
03-31 09:32:13.866 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoActivity onActivityCreated - (chamada para o metodo assíncrono)
03-31 09:32:13.951 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: FragmentosPeriodosAnterioresActivity onStart
03-31 09:32:13.951 25105-25174/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: AsyncBlock doInBackground
03-31 09:32:13.951 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoGraphActivity onStart - (Testativa de recuperar os dados aqui)
03-31 09:32:13.951 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoActivity onStart
03-31 09:32:14.373 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoActivity AsyncCallBack
03-31 09:32:14.412 25105-25105/com.amend.cockpit D/LifeCicle: PeriodoActivity list putExtras - (meu ArrayList é populado somente aqui)
```

Comment: Está a sua pergunta está difícil de entender(pelo menos para mim). É possível você esquecer a sua app e colocar a dúvida num cenário mais simples que possa ser reproduzido?

Comment: Meu método assíncrono sempre é executado por último antes dos fragmentos carregarem, e meu gráfico não recebe os dados.

É meu primeiro contato com metodos assíncronos, portanto minha dúvida é se a execução do método assíncrono de um fragmento A pode ser atrasado para que um fragmento B possa pegar os dados, depois que o método assíncrono execute e popule os dados pra minha ArrayList.

Comment: Por que não coloca esse método no fragmento B?

Comment: No princípio estava ocorrendo outro erro "such instance field" ao executar o método assíncrono no fragmento B.
Mas coloquei a rotina dentro do método assincrono do fragmento B, meu ArrayList foi populado, agora meu AndroidPlot ainda não desenhou o gráfico que vou descobrir. Agradeço o apoio!